# What would prevent me from putting brains in vats?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, intentionality

Following Putnam, I cannot possibly be a brain in a vat, because (if my understanding is correct) I can only refer to "vats" that are not the ones in which I suggest my brain could be.

But what would prevent me from putting actual brains in vats and simulate a fake world for them (if I was able to)? Are they brains in vats but not "brains*" in "vats*" ? ("*" means "in the world I simulate for them")

If this is true, I could be a "brain!" in a "vat!" ("!" means "in a world someone simulates for me")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your objection holds, but only in a world in which the technology actually exists to put a brain in a vat and simulate a world.  In that case you could presumably experience, from the outside, a vat in your pre-brain-in-vat existence, and later correctly surmise that you had been placed in just such a vat at some point in your existence.

In a world without such a technology, however, any such scenario would have to presuppose a deeper level of reality to which you had never had access, which I believe is Putnam's scenario.

The fact that we seem closer and closer to the reality of a brain-in-vat technology in real* life perhaps changes intuitions about this argument.

**to the best of our knowledge*